# What does embedding a language into another do?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, embedding

This may be kind of basic but... here goes.

If I decide to embed some kind of scripting language like Lua or Ruby into a C++ program by linking it's interpreter what does that allow me to do in C++ then?

Would I be able to write Ruby or Lua code right into the cpp file or simply call scripts from the program?

If the latter is true, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're scripting languages, the code is always going to be "interpreted."  In reality, you aren't "calling" the script code inside your program, but rather when you reach that point, you're executing the interpreter in the context of that thread (the thread that reaches the scripting portion), which then reads the scripting language and executes the applicable machine code after interpreting it (JIT compiling kind of, but not really, there's no compiling involved).

Because of this, its basically the same thing as forking the interpreter and running the script, unless you want access to variables in your compiled program/in your script from the compiled program.  To access values to/from, because you're using the thread that has your compiled program's context, you should be able to store script variables on the stack as well and access them when your thread stops running the interpreter (assuming you stored the variables on the stack).

Edit: response:

You would have to write it yourself.  Think about it this way:  if you want to use assembly in c++, you use the asm keyword.  You then in the c++ compiler, need to parse the source file, get to the asm keyword, and then switch to the assembly compiler.  Then the assembly compiler needs to go until the end bracket of the asm region and compile this code.

If you want to do this,it will be a bit different, since assembly gets compiled, not interpreted (which is what you want to do).  What you'll need to do, is change the compiler you're using (lets say c++), so that it recognizes your own user defined keyword.  Lets say this keyword is scriptX{}.  You need to change the c++'s parser so that when it see's scriptX{}, it stores everything between the brackets in the readonly data section of your compiled program.  You then need to add a hook in the compiled assembly file to switch the context of the thread to your script interpreter, and start the program counter at the beginning of your script section (which you put in read only data section of the object file).

Good luck with that...

Comment: So I'm basically making my program both the program and the interpreter? I'm guessing that the functions to call scripts from a setup like that would be in the scripting languages doc somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

A common reason to embed a scripting language into a program is to provide for the ability to control the program with scripts provided by the end user.

Probably the simplest example of such a script is a configuration file. Assume that your program has options, and needs to remember the options from run to run. You could write them out to a file as a binary image of your options structure, but that would be fragile, not easy to inspect or edit, and likely not portable across systems. Writing the options out in plain text with some sort of labels for which is which addresses most of those complaints, but now you need to parse that text and recover the options. Then some users want different options on Tuesdays, want to do simple arithmetic to compute one option from another, or to write one configuration file that they can use on both Windows and Linux, and pretty soon you find yourself inventing a little language to express all of those ideas and mechanisms with. At this point, there's a better way.

The languages [Lua](http://www.lua.org) and [TCL](http://www.tcl.tk/) both grew out of essentially that scenario. Larger systems needed to be configured and controlled by end users. End users wanted to edit a simple text file and get immediate satisfaction, even (especially) when working with large systems that might have required hours to compile successfully.

One advantage here is that rather than inventing a programming language one feature at a time as user's needs change, you start with a complete language along with its documentation. The language designer has already made a number of tough decisions for you (how do I represent strings and numbers, what about lists, what about named values, what does `if` look like, etc.) and has generally also brought a carefully designed and debugged implementation to the table.

Lua is particularly easy to integrate. Reading a simple configuration file and extracting the settings from the Lua state can be done using a small subset of its C API. Once you have Lua available, it is attractive to use it for other purposes. In many cases, you will find that it is more productive to write only the innermost loops in C, and use Lua to glue those functions together and provide all the "business logic" of the application. This is how Adobe Lightroom is implemented, as well as *many* games on platforms ranging from simple set-top-boxes to iOS devices and even PCs.